# Mvp + The Clean Architecture (Чистая Архитектура) куда отнести Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день к какому слою(layer) BroadcastReceiver в Mvp + The Clean Architecture (Чистая Архитектура) и где его разместить в структуре проекта???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BroadcastReceiver можно отнести Cross cutting concern(перекрестная зависимость)

Если смотреть на диаграмму [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то BroadCastReceiver это и Devices & ExternalInterfaces те в Frameworkds and Drivers и они лежат в одном слое, поэтому здесь нет проблем. В проекте это скорей всего будет **Infrastructure layer**.

Не забывайте что BroadCast мб Global/Local что может повлиять на место в архитектуре. У нас были споры по этому поводу, но когда мы начали указывать нужные Scope в котором используется, то стало намного проще.

Comment: Тоесть они дают экшен для вьюхи?я правильно вас понял??

Comment: Я не могу осознать, как из этого ответа можно сделать такой вывод? Отнюдь, не правильно. ExtInterfaces -> Presenters -> UseCases это в вашем случае.

Comment: тоесть у перезентера будет EI который будет в broad и он будет давать иверты в презентер